# How would the Supremacy's size compare to the second Death Star?

Tags: star-wars, spaceship, space-station

I have heard that the [Supremacy](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Supremacy) is the largest ship in Star Wars current canon, but how does it compare to the second [Death Star](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Second_Death_Star) that is the largest artificial moon?

PS: I know that this might be a pain as the Death Star was circular while the supremacy is arrow-shaped.

Comment: The Death Stars were spherical, not round.  A round object could be flat or flattish like a pancake or a flying saucer.  That it what annoys me about talking about round Earth or flat Earth.  A round world can be spherical, like Earth actually is, or flat and round, like a disc, so talking about round vs flat is illogical.

Comment: @M.A.Golding I'd argue that's pedantic: no one mistakes "round" in this case to [not mean spherical](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/round#Adjective). One could additionally nitpick and say the Earth isn't spherical, but instead is much better approximated with an oblate spheroid... doing so, however, does not add any real substance to the conversation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This diagram shows the (approximate) relative sizes of the Supremacy, Death Star I and Death Star II as well as various other large Imperial craft such as the Executor.

You may wish to note that the canonical size of the Death Star II is [200KM](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Rogue_One:_Death_Star_Deluxe_Book_and_3D_Wood_Model)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is correct but here goes:
-The second Death Star was [200km wide](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Star_II), assuming "wide" means diameter
-The supremacy had a width of 60.5km (60,542.68 meters)

This is what a scaled image of them would look like:
[image]

Comment: This is the first time I hear the "200km wide" figure. What's the source? Because I've heard numbers from 160km wide to 980km wide, and if we get yet another one to the list I'm going to get a migraine

Comment: @Petersaber attached a source, from Wookiepedia

Comment: So the source is "Star Wars: Rogue One: Death Star Deluxe Book and 3D Wood Model". Isn't that a model book? Meanwhile, "Death Star Owner's Technical Manual" says it was 160km wide.

Comment: @Petersaber In Legends it was.